# How to move the sprite in Tkinter for 2d game

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a problem with implementing character movement in a 2d game on Tkinter. (The game was created from the book "Python for Children" by Jason R. Briggs). The character stands rooted to the spot and does not respond to control.

I know that the collided left function does not work properly, it works when there are no sprites near the character. Because the parameter x is always = 0. Why is this function not working properly?

```py
def within_y (co1,co2):
    return co1.y1 < co2.y1 < co1.y2 or co1.y1 < co2.y2 < co1.y2 

def collided_left (co1,co2):   
    if within_y(co1,co2) :
        if co2.x1 <= co1.x1 <= co2.x2 :
            return True
    return False

def collided_right (co1,co2):   
    if within_y(co1,co2) :
        if co1.x2 >= co2.x1 and co1.x2 <= co2.x2:
            return True
    return False
```

```
if left and self.x < 0 and collided_left(co , sprite_co) :
                self.x = 0
                left = False
                print("ERROR")
```

Comment: "why isn't this code working" is not an appropriate question for this site. Can you reduce this code down to a [mcve]? Do we really need every line that you posted in order to reproduce your problem?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? have you examined the variables in `with_y` to see if they are what you expect? Have you set up some unit tests to pass in known values to see if the functions return expected results? Also, you should use parentheses around your logical expressions (`co1.y1 < co2.y1 ...`) so that we understand what your intent is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the coordinates. I made a mistake in writing the variable, as a result of the following collision functions did not work correctly in the wrong coordinates. Thank you, Bryan Oakley, for helping me and for the suggestion, check the coordinates.